# How to get a list of all instances of an object on a page

Tags: c#, wpf, silverlight

On a Silverlight page there are a number of instances of a custom control. I can easily get an instance of the custom control by its name:

```
MyCustomControl mcc = (MyCustomControl)this.FindName(namestring);
```

But how could I get a list of all the instances of this custom control on this page?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this class to your project:-

```
public static class VisualTreeEnumeration
{
    public static IEnumerable<DependencyObject> Descendents(this DependencyObject root)
    {
        int count = VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(root);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(root, i);
            yield return child;
            foreach (var descendent in Descendents(child))
                yield return descendent;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can use this code:-

```
 List<MyCustomControl> = this.Descendents().OfType<MyCustomControl>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
Enumerable.Range(0, VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(this))
    .Select(i => VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(this, i))
    .Where(c => c is MyUserControl);
```

Comment: Thank you! +1 Could you please give a tip on how to get results to a List<MyCustomControl> out of this? I've tried "var ret = Enumerable.Range(.." and then "foreach (MyCustomControl sci in ret){...}" but the List is empty

Comment: Add .ToList() at the end of the line of code I posted earlier

Comment: Unfortunately, it's all the same empty

Comment: If your usercontrols are inside another panel (eg grid), then give the grid a name, and then use the name instead of the 'this' reference in the above code